# How to limit this query to only those books that have more than one author?

Tags: oracle

I have been trying to limit this query to books with more than one author (should be four), but I can not figure it out. Can someone please help?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(authorid) AS "Number of Authors"
FROM book_author, books, publisher
    WHERE publisher.pubid(+) = books.pubid
        AND books.bookid(+) = book_author.bookid
            GROUP BY title;
```

Here are the results:

```
    SQL> SELECT title, COUNT(authorid) AS "Number of Authors"
  2   FROM book_author, books, publisher
  3    WHERE publisher.pubid(+) = books.pubid
  4     AND books.bookid(+) = book_author.bookid
  5      GROUP BY title;

TITLE                          Number of Authors
------------------------------ -----------------
DATABASE IMPLEMENTATION                        3
PAINLESS CHILD-REARING                         3
HOW TO GET FASTER PIZZA                        1
SHORTEST POEMS                                 1
BIG BEAR AND LITTLE DOVE                       1
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY                  2
HOLY GRAIL OF ORACLE                           1
HANDCRANKED COMPUTERS                          2
HOW TO MANAGE THE MANAGER                      1
COOKING WITH MUSHROOMS                         1
BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS                 1
E-BUSINESS THE EASY WAY                        1
REVENGE OF MICKEY                              1
THE WOK WAY TO COOK                            1

14 rows selected.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to limit your results to books that have more than one author?  Or authors that wrote more than one book?  You're asking about authors that wrote more than one book.  But your query only sensibly can be limited to books that have more than one author.

Comment: Right, I worded it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause will filter aggregate values:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(authorid) AS "Number of Authors"
FROM book_author, books, publisher
WHERE publisher.pubid(+) = books.pubid
  AND books.bookid(+) = book_author.bookid
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(authorid) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying everything but that. I was using WHERE count(authorid) > 1. I forgot about the HAVING clause.

Comment: Moreover, I just found the example in my notes. I'm soo tired, my eyes hurt.

Comment: No worries - we've all been there :)